# Узнать\расчитать размер объекта в сантиметрах

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как в программах типа фотошопа реализована функция "показать в реальном размере"? необходимо реализовать подобный функционал в самом примитивном виде, чтобы некоторый объект на любом мониторе был одинакового размера (в сантиметрах).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если мы говорим о Windows, то автоматическими методами (без калибровки пользователем) это не получится. Причина в том, что Windows *не знает* реального размера экрана вашего монитора.

Вот сходный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652835/getting-actual-screen-dpi-ppi-under-windows

В книжке "The Old New Thing" Р.Чера была заметка на эту тему.

Вариант решения проблемы -- узнавать у Windows модель монитора, иметь большую базу мониторов в которой описаны их физические характеристики. Adobe может себе позволить такую базу иметь и поддерживать в актуальном состоянии.

Дешёвое решение -- сделать в своей программе настройку -- сантиметровая линейка сантиметров на 10 и слайдер. Пользователь прикладывает линейку, двигает слайдер пока не совпадёт.
В частности, такое реализовано в векторном редакторе Inkscape, называется "Zoom correction factor".

Решение для современных мониторов -- достать физические размеры экрана из EDID. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577736/how-to-obtain-the-correct-physical-size-of-the-monitor
Но насколько я понимаю, тут уже вопрос, копирует ли драйвер видеокарты эту информацию из того что отдаёт монитор, или просто генерирует свои данные.